# CSS Table won't change height

Tags: html, css, alignment, height, css-tables

I have this body and CSS for the section #content:

```css
section#content {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
 color: #444;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 7px 18px 21px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 617px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}
section#content .table {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 display: table;
}

section#content table.table {
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

section#content table.table td {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 word-break: break-word;
 transition-property: background;
 transition-duration: 0.1s;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
}

section#content table.table tr:nth-child(even)>td {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}

section#content table.table th {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
 color: #444444;
 font-weight: normal;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
}

section#content .playerTableBackground {
 background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
    background-image: url("pageBG.jpg");
    background-position: center top, center bottom, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: none">
 <section id="content">
  <noscript>
   <div class="messagebox error">
    In deinem Webbrowser ist JavaScript deaktiviert.<br />Um das
    Ticketsystem nutzen zu können, muss JavaScript aktiviert sein.
    Andernfalls ist beispielsweise das Antworten auf Tickets nicht
    möglich.
   </div>
  </noscript>

  <div class="playerTableBackground">
   <table id="playerTable" class="table" style="opacity: 0.9;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sozialer Status</th>
      <th>Spielzeit</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
      <th>Fraktion</th>
      <th>Freundschaft</th>
      <th>Ping</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="playerTableBody">
   </table>
  </div>
 </section>

</body>
```

I can only change the height of the div, but neither the table or tbody. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Your CSS isn't trying to set the height of anything

Comment: What are you trying to do that's not working? I don't know what your question is.

Comment: Usually, the height does not work on an element until it is assigned.

Comment: Because I tried in every class, but it didn't change anything. I expected the section#content .table. But it won't change :(

Comment: `<body style="background: none">` please don't do that, use css instead

Comment: there is nothing in the body. How do you expect to change its height?

Comment: I expected to change the height in the section#content .table class. But if I write "height: 150px;" into it, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you need to have tbody to have a specific height as the data comes dynamically. So my proposition to you is this:

1. Initially show a "data not available" `tr` as per below.
2. When data is ready to be shown to the user mark it as `display: none` and show the data inside the `tbody`.

Hope this helps. Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
section#content {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
 color: #444;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 7px 18px 21px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 617px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}
section#content .table {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 display: table;
}

section#content table.table {
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

section#content table.table td {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 word-break: break-word;
 transition-property: background;
 transition-duration: 0.1s;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
}

section#content table.table tr:nth-child(even)>td {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}

section#content table.table th {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
 color: #444444;
 font-weight: normal;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
}

section#content .playerTableBackground {
 background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
    background-image: url("pageBG.jpg");
    background-position: center top, center bottom, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover;
}

section#content table.table td.empty{
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<body style="background: none">
 <section id="content">
  <noscript>
   <div class="messagebox error">
    In deinem Webbrowser ist JavaScript deaktiviert.<br />Um das
    Ticketsystem nutzen zu können, muss JavaScript aktiviert sein.
    Andernfalls ist beispielsweise das Antworten auf Tickets nicht
    möglich.
   </div>
  </noscript>

  <div class="playerTableBackground">
   <table id="playerTable" class="table" style="opacity: 0.9;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sozialer Status</th>
      <th>Spielzeit</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
      <th>Fraktion</th>
      <th>Freundschaft</th>
      <th>Ping</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="playerTableBody">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="empty" colspan="7">No data available!</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! It Works finally :)

Answer (score 0):

Tables are special.  Setting height on a table is undefined in the specification.  Simply set height on your `TH` instead.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout

> ## 17.5.3 Table height algorithms
>
> The height of a table is given by the 'height' property for the 'table' or 'inline-table' element. A value of 'auto' means that the height is the sum of the row heights plus any cell spacing or borders. Any other value is treated as a minimum height. CSS 2.1 does not define how extra space is distributed when the 'height' property causes the table to be taller than it otherwise would be.

```css
section#content {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
 color: #444;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 7px 18px 21px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 617px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}
section#content .table {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
 display: table;
}

section#content table.table {
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

section#content table.table td {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 word-break: break-word;
 transition-property: background;
 transition-duration: 0.1s;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
}

section#content table.table tr:nth-child(even)>td {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}

section#content table.table th {
 height: 45px;
 background-color: #ebebeb;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
 color: #444444;
 font-weight: normal;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
}

section#content .playerTableBackground {
 background-attachment: scroll, scroll, fixed;
    background-image: url("pageBG.jpg");
    background-position: center top, center bottom, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: none">
 <section id="content">
  <noscript>
   <div class="messagebox error">
    In deinem Webbrowser ist JavaScript deaktiviert.<br />Um das
    Ticketsystem nutzen zu können, muss JavaScript aktiviert sein.
    Andernfalls ist beispielsweise das Antworten auf Tickets nicht
    möglich.
   </div>
  </noscript>

  <div class="playerTableBackground">
   <table id="playerTable" class="table" style="opacity: 0.9;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sozialer Status</th>
      <th>Spielzeit</th>
      <th>Telefon</th>
      <th>Fraktion</th>
      <th>Freundschaft</th>
      <th>Ping</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="playerTableBody">
   </table>
  </div>
 </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want to change the height of my tbody. Its empty here, because the data come out of jquery.
Thanks for your help in advice!